# Выполнение параллельных потоков в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Пользуюсь `AsyncTask` для создания отдельного потока для постоянного вызова нативной функции. Все замечательно работало до тех пор, пока не понадобилось создать второй поток. Программа тупо зависает на `execute()` и ждет, пока первый поток завершится.

Чем лечить? Как создавать несколько потоков не блокирующих друг друга?

Comment: Может у вас функция синхронизирована? Добавьте код.

Comment: Использую вот такую обертку: https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/centerix/zverus/zverus/MAutoSync.java , виснет например тут https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/centerix/zverus/zverus/ZverusLoginActivity.java#L39 , при перезапуске ативити один AsyncTask продолжал работать и все висло на втором.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

До версии Android 1.6 при запуске задач `AsyncTask` использовалось только два потока:основной - UI и пользовательский - User. При этом если в пользовательском потоке запускалось более одной задачи, то остальные дожидались своей очереди на выполнение, пока все, что запущенны ранее не отработают свои задачи.То есть мы имели ни что иное, как двухзадачность. И увидели в Google, что это плохо.

с Android 1.6 ввели следующие изменения:
Первые пять потоков запускались параллельно, а шестой и последующие дожидались, когда освободится какой то из первых пяти, но при этом, если очередь становилась более 10 потоков, то 16 и последующие вновь запускались параллельно (всего до 128), а те несчастливые с пятого до пятнадцатого так и ждали, когда освободится им место. Кроме того было отведено определенное время (10 секунд, а с Android 2.3 - 1 секунда)- если в течении этого времени появлялись еще новые потоки, то при завершении первых пяти они запускались вперед все тех же несчастных с пятого до пятнадцатого. Как видите в такой схеме разобраться очень не просто, она не очевидна и крайне запутана - программисты допускали множество ошибок и гугл засыпали жалобами.

С android 3.0 опять были введены изменения. В `AsyncTask` появился новый метод `executeOnExecutor()` , который имел два ключа:

1. `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` - параллельное выполнение потоков по страшной  схеме, применяемой в Android 2.3
2. `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` - последовательное выполнение потоков по схеме до android 1.6

метод `execute()` так же был оставлен для обратной совместимости, теперь он позволяет запустить **последовательно** 128 потоков. ( Работает по схеме применяемой до Android 1.6)

На сегодняшний день, если вы желаете, чтобы ваши потоки выполнялись параллельно, их следует запускать следующим образом (работает с API 11):

```
 asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Если минимальная версия вашего приложения меньше API 11 (Android 3.0), то вам придется придумывать какие то костыли, чтобы совместить желаемое поведение при запуске потоков, учитывая информацию выше, например:

```
public static void execute(AsyncTask as) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
      as.execute();
  } else {
      as.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
  }
}
```

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! Полезная инфа про AstncTask!