# AsyncTask. Максимальное число одновременных потоков

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Доброго времени суток! Есть `Android` приложение в котором активно используются асинхронные задачи. Допустим этих задач 800 штук и их надо асинхронно выполнять. Можно просто взять и запустить их все вместе и ждать когда они все выполнятся. Но проблема в том, что вываливается `RejectedExecution`,  насколько я понимаю, из за того, что превышено предельное количество одновременно действующих потоков в пуле (800 одновременных потоков - это явно многовато). 
Напрашивается такое решение: запускать их "пачками" например по 10 штук. Если одна задача закончила выполнение, запускать другую и  так далее пока не выполнятся все. Но как это реализовать? Как сделать так чтобы число одновременно выполняющихся `AsyncTask` было не больше 10 и при этом по окончании каждой задачи запускалась новая из числа ожидающих? Или может существуют уже какие-то готовые способы распланировать выполнение слишком  большого числа одновременных задач и изобретать велосипеды не нужно? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какие вы данные грузите? Нельзя ли обойтись меньшим количеством? И вам их сразу необходимо отображать именно по одному?

Comment: обойтись меньшим количеством нельзя. Данные - это файлы, загружаемые из сети.

Comment: и необходимо сразу же отображать его, сразу после загрузки?

Comment: Я не понимаю что значит сразу же отображать после загрузки. Отображать где и как?  И какое это имеет отношение к планированию этих тасков?

Comment: Большое, если вам просто необходимо загрузить файлы, это совсем другая задача и AsynkTask вам не нужен, он предназначен для загрузки и после отображения данных.

Comment: давайте предположим что AsyncTask мне очень нужен. Переписывать тонны кода я не имею возможности даже если это стоит сделать

Comment: Одновременно можно запустить до 128 потоков. [Некоторые тонкости](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424762/177345) устройства `AsyncTask` в android

Answer (score 1):

Используйте класс `Executors` и в нем статический метод `newFixedThreadPool(n)`, который вернет экземпляр `ExecutorService`. Эта конструкция поможет организовать очередь потоков из n одновременно запущенных, остальные будут стоять в очереди. Хороший пример [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116363/). 
**UPD**
Пример, использует очередь из 200 потоков, из которых одновременно выполняются только два:

```
void test() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            executorService.submit(getRunnable(i));
        }
}

Runnable getRunnable(final int i) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("test2", "начало "+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("test2", "конец " + i);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: но не более 128 всего, включая очередь.Очевидно ваш ответ никак не поможет в решении вопроса.

Comment: @pavlofff как вариант можно отойти от AsyncTask, и просто работать с Executors

Answer (score 0):

Лучшим решением думаю будет переписать код, так как если пользователь выйдет из приложения, загруженные файлы вы не получите, не сработает метод `onPostExecute()`. Лучше подойдет связка [IntentService](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/165-urok-100-service-intentservice-foreground-avtozagruzka-servisa.html) и [ExecutorService](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/160-urok-95-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-pendingintent.html). Тогда вы будете в любом случае получать загруженные файлы и сможете сохранить их. `ExecutorService` возьмет на себя обязанность ограничения потоков.

Comment: переписывание кода не вариант. Если пользователь выйдет из приложения то не получение файлов будет являться нормальным ожидаемым результатом, это не проблема. Интересует решение именно в рамках AsyncTask