# Как синхронизировать две "тяжелые" задачи: AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

Есть два последовательных вызова "тяжелых" задач:

```
new Task1(this).execute("http://site1");
new Task2(this).execute("http://site2");
```

Task2 должен начинать выполняться ТОЛЬКО по завершению Task1.
 Какие есть варианты их синхронизировать?

Спасибо.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424762/177345

Comment: Запустить ```Task2``` в ```onPostExecute() ``` первой задачи не вариант?

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал.