# Реализация очереди AsynsTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Вообщем у меня в программе можно загружать музыку из интернета, и я хочу сделать очередь загрузок(что бы если пользователь загружал несколько песен подряд они загружались одна за другой). Я думаю сделать это так. Создать массив с данными загрузки и при нажатии скачать добавлять данные в массив, затем создать метод, который проверял бы этот массив в если AsynsTask не активный то запускал бы его. Вопрос. Это нормальная реализация и как правильно написать метод проверки массива на наличие песен для загрузки?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете просто создавать новые задачи для `AsyncTask` по мере надобности. С   ключом `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` они будут выполнятся последовательно.

Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424762/177345) для подробностей.

PS: действительно для API14 и выше.

Comment: Не совсем понял executeOnExecutor заменяет execute. А где писать параметры?

Comment: С API14 не заменяет, а дублирует - с ключом `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR`. Внимательно читайте ответ по ссылке. Там все написано и есть примеры вызовов.