# SQlite работа в нескольких потоках одновременно

Tags: android, sqlite

Мое приложение работает с БД `SQLite`, недавно дописал фоновый сервис который независимо от пользователя работает с БД (делает очень много изменений в транзакциях и не только).
Проблема заключается в том, что как только из активити пользователь нажимает действие, которое приводит к записи в БД, и если сервис не закончил работу или только запустился, приводит к вылету, т.к. БД заблокирована.
Как работать с БД в таких случаях? Блокировать UI на время работы сервиса - мне кажется это плохая идея, т.к. на разных устройствах время выполнения работы с БД в сервисе может занимать от 1 до нескольких десятков секунд.

Comment: Делать запись в отдельном потоке, а объект обращения к БД обернуть в synhronized {} https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1055-sinkhronizacija-potokov-blokirovka-obhhekta-i-blokirovka-klassa.

Comment: Читайте материалы в Интернете по Android приложениям, лучше всего в официальных источниках, Хорошие примеры работы - Room как БД совместно с RxJava (асинхронность)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас должен быть некий класс для работы с бд, и все действия вы проводите через него. Никаких обращений к бд в основном потоке, ни в коем случае. Даже очень простой запрос пожет встать на полсекунды, если кто-то использует диск. Сделайте свой лупер и добавляйте в него запросы с колбэками

Comment: как [выполняются потоки AsyncTask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424762/177345) в Android

Comment: ну, значит ну их эти асинк таски) Уберу их из ответа. Свой лупер для работы с базой

Comment: Если честно, то я ничего не понял. Чем плохи запросы в основном потоке? Ссылку или пример алгоритма?

Comment: Когда вы обращаетесь к таким медленным подсистемам, как файловая система или сеть, из основного потока - ваш UI встанет намертво. Ни анимаций, ни реаций на нажатия, ничего. К сети вам андроид не даст обратится, вылетит с ошибкой. Родной sqlite интерфейс позволит обратится к базе из основного потока, но это не значит что стоит так делать. Room уже не даст вам работать с базой из основного потока. Лучше нарисуйте в нужном месте прогрессбар и сделайте запрос к базе асинхронно, тогда UI не будет зависать на время запроса. Примером на что поделиться?

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, мне не хватает знаний чтобы понять алгоритм работы подобных классов. Поэтому я прошу пример, где в БД можно параллельно отправить несколько различных запросов, время выполнения которых не известно, и не заставлять пользователя постоянно наблюдать за прогресс барами и подобным.